# why method declared in Mongoose schema wasnt working

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, bcrypt

So, here's my user schema where i declared hello method onto the Userschema which im using to test

```
//user.model.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 3
  },
  password: { type: String, required: true }
});


UserSchema.methods.hello = () => {
  console.log("hello from method");
};

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

here's routes file

```
//authroutes.js
const router = require("express").Router();
let User = require("../models/user.model");

router.route("/").get((req, res) => {
  res.send("auth route");
});

router.route("/signup").post((req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  const newUser = new User({
    username,
    password
  });

  newUser
    .save()
    .then(() => res.json(`${username} added`))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

router.route("/login").post(async (req, res) => {
  await User.find({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;

    //this doesnt work
    user.hello();
    res.end();
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

in the login route im calling hello function to test but that doesnt work and throws this error

> TypeError: user.hello is not a function

Comment: what you are getting in user variable??

Comment: @pu this  ` [
  {
    _id: 5e32c0e7d2a08d6c10768089,
    username: 'rohit',
    password: '$2b$10$RQir9GkQL/A604QwH3c5fOANFJ20DpUU7pn/IIsVNLzCdb.j7lVim',
    __v: 0
  }
]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `User.findOne` instead of `User.find`, because find returns an array, but what we need is an instance of the model.

Also [Instance methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) shouldn't be declared  using ES6 arrow functions.
Arrow functions explicitly prevent binding this, so your method will not have access to the document and it will not work.

So you had better to update method like this:

```js
UserSchema.methods.hello = function() {
  console.log("hello from method");
};
```

Comment: no it wasnt working, can you please look at this image so you can get a idea https://i.imgur.com/XfvXKKO.png , my post request is this https://i.imgur.com/H6xMaew.png